# Sorted tree view in htop or alternative?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, top, htop

I am running a Debian flavor of Linux, and I use htop to keep track of memory usage, since it is more detailed than top. I can't seem to get it to sort by memory *and* display process trees at the same time. Is there a way to do this with htop or an alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like [Glances](https://glances.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) should have what you need:

```
glances --tree
```

And then sort using commands `m`,`t`, `i` etc.  [Full command reference](http://glances.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cmds.html#interactive-commands)

Comment: This option was removed last year: https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/commit/631722992e76827ecee61797edd3ab218e28c94a

Comment: did anyone figure out an alternative to this now that even glances can't do it?

Answer (score 11):

A 2019 update on this 2014 question that ranked highly when searching for this topic is that htop has this built in now, and in the current version 2.2.0, simply pressing <kbd>t</kbd> in the default view generates a process hierarchy.

Comment: I don't think this answers his question since pressing `t` only changes view to tree but keeps not allowing you to sort at the same time. I'm using version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

Not with `htop` (and probably with any other alternative) as both views are mutually exclusive: either you list processes sorted by memory, or respect the PPID/PID tree view. You can have both at the same time.

Comment: Sure, but since there is a hierarchical relationship there, you could aggregate the memory or CPU usage of the tree and then sort on that.

Comment: On one of my server htop 1.0.1 does indeed lists the processes and their threads in tree view *and* sorted by CPU% (based on the process cpu%). On my other server, there is htop 1.0.2 and setting `sort by CPU%` automatically clears the tree view.

Comment: To clarify what @TrevorAlexander said, siblings in the tree could be sorted against one another without breaking the tree display

Answer (score 1):

In htop version 3 (I believe, 3.0.3 to be exact) you can sort by other columns than pid even in tree mode.

See the [changelog](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/blob/main/ChangeLog).

It's not perfect, because it doesn't aggregate memory from sub processes, but it's a nice feature nonetheless.